# Fixed-sized length/ M/ 1 queuing model

Tags: queueing-theory

Let's say we have a queue with size n, for example 30, no item will be added to the queue, the size of the queue is fixed, arrival rate is zero. There is one server with shifted exponential service  distribution, for example it takes at least 1 minute for the server to give the service to the each item in the queue. In addition, on average 2 added minutes the server needs for each item. It means the $PDF$ of service distribution is: $\frac{1}{2} e^{-1/2(t-1)}$

1 - What is probability the at certain time $t_1$, exactly $k$ items out of n items have been serviced?

2 - By time time $t_1$, we expect how many items have been serviced?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: What do you mean "on average 2 added minutes the server needs for each item?"  Is the real service time exponential with average $3$ minutes?  What are the added minutes?

Comment: It means on average server needs 2 extra minutes  to give the service. the minimum time the server needs to give the service is one minutes, but on it also needs 2 extra minutes.  Service distribution is 1 minute shifted exponential with parameter $\lambda$ = 2

Comment: On average usually implies some randomness.  You are implying that we should consider it a fixed value.  If so, you should say that.  Your proposed distribution function integrates to $1$ if we integrate from $1$ to $\infty$ but I don't see why we should start there.

Comment: It is just like a bank line with a fixed number of people in the line, say 50 people, and no one will join the line afterwards. There is one teller. The minimum amount of time taken by each customer to be given the service is one minute. It means it is not possible for the teller to give the service to a customer in less than one minute. However, on average, it takes two more minutes for the teller to give service to a customer. it means perhaps it takes one extra minute, 3 extra minutes, 0.5 extra minutes so on, but on average the teller gives 2 more minutes to each customer.

Answer (score 0):

Denote by $S_k=X_1+\ldots+X_k=k+Y_1+\ldots+Y_k$ the total service time of first $k$ customers. Here $Y_i$ have PDF $\frac12 e^{-\frac12t}\mathbb 1_{\{t>0\}}$. Let $Z_k=Y_1+\ldots+Y_k$.

The first question asks on the probability that $S_k\leq t_1$,  $S_{k+1}>t_1$. Write it:
$$
\mathbb P(S_k\leq t_1, \ S_{k+1}>t_1)=\mathbb P(S_k\leq t_1) -\mathbb P( S_{k+1}\leq t_1) $$
$$=\mathbb P(Z_k\leq t_1-k) - \mathbb P(Z_{k+1}\leq t_1-k-1)
$$
Next use that $Z_m$ is Gamma-distributed (or Erlang distributed) with PDF 
$$f_{Z_m}(s)=\frac{1}{2^m(m-1)!} s^{m-1}e^{-\frac12s}\mathbb 1_{\{s>0\}}.$$
The desired probability equals to the difference of CDF's of $Z_k$ and $Z_{k+1}$ in the points $t_1-k$ and $t_1-k-1$ respectively: 
$$
F_{Z_k}(t_1-k)-F_{Z_{k+1}}(t_1-k-1)
$$
It can be expressed as a difference of two sums, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function_(CDF).

To find expectation of number $N$ of served customers up to time $t_1$, one do not need to find $\mathbb P(N=k)$ which is calculated above. Let us use the first step only: 
$$
\mathbb P(N=k)=\mathbb P(S_k\leq t_1, \ S_{k+1}>t_1)=\mathbb P(S_k\leq t_1) -\mathbb P( S_{k+1}\leq t_1) $$
Next,
$$
\mathbb E[N] = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k\mathbb P(N=k)
$$
$$ = 1\cdot(\mathbb P(S_1\leq t_1) -\mathbb P( S_2\leq t_1))
$$
$$+2\cdot(\mathbb P(S_2\leq t_1) -\mathbb P( S_3\leq t_1))
$$
$$+3\cdot(\mathbb P(S_3\leq t_1) -\mathbb P( S_4\leq t_1)) + \ldots
$$
$$
=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb P(S_k\leq t_1)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb P(Z_k\leq t_1-k)=\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor{t_1}\rfloor}\int\limits_0^{t_1-k} \frac{1}{2^k(k-1)!} t^{k-1}e^{-\frac12t}\,dt.
$$
Doubt that it is possible to simplify this integral.